# Auto match unique string and populate it with data from another CSV

Tags: macos, csv, automation, apple-numbers

I don't know what is the correct term for this, but I just want to populate a new column with data from another csv.

For example I have this data with a new column, let's call it CSV 1 (3rd column is blank).

```
Order #, SKU, cost
ORDER-A, SKU001
ORDER-B, SKU001
ORDER-C, SKU002
ORDER-C, SKU003
ORDER-C, SKU004
ORDER-C, SKU005
ORDER-D, SKU001
ORDER-D, SKU002
ORDER-D, SKU003
ORDER-D, SKU004
```

Then I have separate CSV with these values, let's call this CSV 2:

```
SKU, cost
SKU001, 100
SKU002, 150
SKU003, 200
SKU004, 220
```

And so on...

How can I auto populate the first CSV file to match the SKU column from the second CSV file that I have?

PS: I'm using Numbers for Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified which language/program you're using here, but assuming it's excel you can use the VLOOKUP function. If CSV 1 is in cells A1:C11 and CSV 2 is in cells D1:E5, in cell B2 (cost column of CSV 1) enter the formula: 
`=VLOOKUP(B1,$D$2:$E$5,2,0)`

Comment: Hi buzz. Sorry I'm using "Numbers" for Mac. Can't seem to find any instructions online regarding Vlookup on Numbers.